# Two Partial Views, posting data to actions causing issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, partial-views

I am using MVC 4 for a project. one of my view has 2 partial views in it as:

```
<div id="fPassword">
      @Html.Partial("_ForgotPassword",new UserForgotPasswordModel())
</div>
<div id="aLink">
      @Html.Partial("_ActivationLink", new UserActivationLinkModel())
</div>
```

The Partial Views are as:

```
@model Me2Everyone.Web.UI.Models.User.UserForgotPasswordModel
@using (Html.BeginForm("ForgotPassword", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "personal-form" }))
{
<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="padding: 0px 0 20px 0;">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td width="375">
                <div class="text-problem">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Email)
                </div>
            </td>
            <td width="80" valign="bottom">
                <input type="submit" value="Send" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
}
```

and the second one is almost same to above the only difference is model type and action method of Form.

In Home Controller the ForgotPassword action is as:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ForgotPassword(UserForgotPasswordModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // Search email in database.
        if(emailNotFound)
        {
            model.ErrorMessage = "Email not found.";
        }
    }
    else
    {
         model.ErrorMessage = "Email address not found.";
    }
    return PartialView("_ForgotPassword", model);
}
```

Now when I was posting data to server, it was returning the partial view as independent not in the main View, so I looked around on net and found that I need to send ajax call for it, so I did it as in the parent view as:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("form").submit(function () {
            if ($(this).valid()) {
                var dataToSend = { model: { Email: $("#Email").val() } };
                var serializedForm = $(this).serialize();
                var isForgotPassword = true;
                if ($(this).attr('action').indexOf("ForgotPassword") < 0)
                    isForgotPassword = false;
                $.ajax({
                url: $(this).attr('action'),
                data: serializedForm,
                type: 'POST',
                success: function (data, textStatus, request) {
                    if (isForgotPassword == true)
                        $("#fPassword").html(data);
                    else
                        $("#aLink").html(data);
                },
                error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError)
                {
                    alert('error')
                }
            });
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

and also in my parent view I have:

```
@if(Model.ErrorMessage != "")
{
     <script type="text/javascript">
          alert(@Model.ErrorMessage);
     </script>
}
```

The problem is when I give a valid email address, it works fine but when I provide an email address that doesnot exist in database, I get the alert that Email not found but when I click again on the submit button, the partial view is created independently in browser instead of being in parent view.

I tried by changing my parent view as:

```
 <div id="fPassword">
      @{Html.RenderAction("ForgotPassword");}
 </div>
 <div id="aLink">
       @{Html.RenderAction("ActivationLink");}
</div>
```

but still its not working, any ideas or help on it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace:

```
$("form").submit(function () {
```

with:

```
$(document).on('submit', 'form', function () {
```

This will ensure that your submit handler is registered in a *lively* manner. This means that after you refresh your DOM with contents coming from the AJAX call, the submit handler that you registered will continue to be associated to this new form. You could read more about the [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method in the documentation. The `.on()` replaces the deprecated (and even removed in jQuery 1.9) [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) method which allowed you to achieve the same task. After the `.live()` method was deprecated, they introduced the [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) method with the same semantics. So depending on the jQuery version you are using, you should pick the right method.